# androidx jetifier failed to transform com.android.tools.common 26.4.2

Tags: java, androidx

Can anyone help with this:

I am compiling an android application in android studio 3.5.2 (with everything up to date in the sdk) and get the following error linked to app:javaPreCompileDebug:

The error message is

```
The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.
```

I've appended a full stacktrace below if anyone can decipher.  The error seems to be occurring when transforming com.android.tools/common/26.4.2/71f8d5ea1ddb6bfe3fb100e0642262951e11e304/common-26.4.2.jar' using Jetifier.

I can't find anywhere in my project that I am using com.android.tools v26.4.2 although it is mentioned in the project structure/all modules but I don't know where these references come from:

```
com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.4.2
com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.4.2
com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.4.2
com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.4.2
com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04
com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta04
com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.4.2
com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.4.2
com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.4.2
com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.4.2
com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.2
com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.7.2
com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.4.2
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2
com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.4.2
com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api
com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.4.2
com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.4.2
com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.4.2
com.android.tools:annotations:26.4.2
com.android.tools:common:26.4.2
com.android.tools:dvlib:26.4.2
com.android.tools:repository:26.4.2
com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.4.2
com.android.tools:sdklib:26.4.2
```

Here is the stacktrace....

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$FileCollectionLeafVisitorImpl.visitCollection(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(AbstractFileCollection.java:233)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:205)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskFingerprinter.fingerprintTaskFiles(DefaultTaskFingerprinter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.createExecutionState(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform artifact 'common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.4.2)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.lambda$visitArtifact$1(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.visitArtifact(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant$SingleArtifactSet.visit(ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformCompletion.visit(TransformCompletion.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.CompositeResolvedArtifactSet$CompositeResult.visit(CompositeResolvedArtifactSet.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:256)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$500(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:231)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifactsWithBuildOperation(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$200(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1167)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /tmp/gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/common/26.4.2/71f8d5ea1ddb6bfe3fb100e0642262951e11e304/common-26.4.2.jar.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$1(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.mapFailure(Try.java:182)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$3(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:194)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:170)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:54)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4717)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3444)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2152)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2042)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3850)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4712)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.invoke(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep.lambda$transform$0(TransformationStep.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Success.flatMap(Try.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep.transform(TransformationStep.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$InitialTransformationNode$1.transform(TransformationNode.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:229)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$InitialTransformationNode.execute(TransformationNode.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNodeExecutor.execute(TransformationNodeExecutor.java:37)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform '/tmp/gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/common/26.4.2/71f8d5ea1ddb6bfe3fb100e0642262951e11e304/common-26.4.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.LegacyTransformer.transform(LegacyTransformer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$TransformerExecution.execute(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:274)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$2(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:148)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.AmbiguousStringJetifierException: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.CoreRemapperImpl.rewriteString(CoreRemapperImpl.kt:91)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.asm.CustomRemapper.mapValue(CustomRemapper.kt:75)
    at org.objectweb.asm.commons.ClassRemapper.visitField(ClassRemapper.java:113)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readField(ClassReader.java:883)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:694)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.ByteCodeTransformer.runTransform(ByteCodeTransformer.kt:39)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:443)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.ArchiveFile.accept(ArchiveFile.kt:49)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:425)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.Archive.accept(Archive.kt:76)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transformLibrary(Processor.kt:421)
    at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform(Processor.kt:247)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:113)
    ... 86 more
```

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to add this dependency to the project:

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'

No idea why this works but it did.

Comment: not worked for me!